# Увеличить числовое значение в объекте

Tags: javascript, массивы, функции, объекты, методы

```
var list1 = [
    { firstName: 'Noah', lastName: 'M.', country: 'Switzerland', continent: 'Europe', age: 19, language: 'C' },
    { firstName: 'Anna', lastName: 'R.', country: 'Liechtenstein', continent: 'Europe', age: 52, language: 'JavaScript' },
    { firstName: 'Ramon', lastName: 'R.', country: 'Paraguay', continent: 'Americas', age: 29, language: 'Ruby' },
    { firstName: 'George', lastName: 'B.', country: 'England', continent: 'Europe', age: 81, language: 'C' },
];

function countLanguages(list) {
    let langObj = {};
    list.forEach(element => {
        if (element.language === "C") {
            langObj[element.language]++;
        } else if (element.language === "JavaScript") {
            langObj[element.language]++;
        } else if (element.language === "Ruby") {
            langObj[element.language]++;
        }
    });
    return console.log(langObj);
};


countLanguages(list1);
```

**Функция должна возвращать объект, в котором перечислены названия языков программирования и количество людей которые ими пользуються.**

В моем коде, функция возвращает NaN. Не понимаю, что пишу неправильно. Подскажите мою ошибку.

Answer (score 2):

```
function countLanguages(list) {
    let langObj = {};
    list.forEach(element => {
        langObj[element.language] = (langObj[element.language] || 0) + 1;
    }
    return langObj;
};

console.log(countLanguages(list1));
```

Comment: В силу своей слабой компетентности для меня такий код пока не очень читабелен, но все равно спасибо за ответ.

Comment: @Vlodek, создаём объект, проходим циклом по массиву с объектами, в созданный объект вставляем название языка и назначаем ему значение = (его же значение или ноль) + 1.